# Create new Google Sheet from Form Respoinses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am using a multi page form to complete 4 tasks different tasked based on the first response to the first question on the first page. One of which is to create a new sheet based on form response. I would like to create a new sheet if one is not already created based on the response from the question "Select The Workers:" and if it is then move the response to that sheet. I found a function from another question that works perfectly except I can not get the sheet to be renamed to the response of the question i.e. "the workers name".

```
function onSubmit(e){
var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
var ss = sheet.getParent();
var form = FormApp.openByUrl(ss.getFormUrl());
// Choose destination sheet according to Select the worker:
var destSheet = getSheet(ss, e.namedValues['Select The Worker:']);
// Store the current response in destination sheet
destSheet.appendRow(e.values);

/**
 * Get the sheet with given name. Create sheet if it doesn't exist.
* New sheet will be created with optional headings, if provided.
*
* From: 
*
* @param {Spreadsheet} spreadsheet   Google Spreadsheet object.
* @param {String}      sheetName     Sheet name to get.
* @param {String[]}    headings      Optional array of headings (for new sheet).
*
* @returns {Sheet}                   Sheet object.
*/
function getSheet( spreadsheet, sheetName, headings ) {
 spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
 if (sheet == null) {
  // Not found, so add new sheet
  sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
  if (headings && headings.constructor === Array) {
   sheet.getRange(1,1,1,headings.length).setValues([headings]);
 }
}

return sheet;
 }
}
```

I am not sure if I am missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that all entries in `namedValues` are [arrays](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit). Try changing `e.namedValues['Select The Worker:']` to `e.namedValues['Select The Worker:'].toString()`

Comment: Thank you Daniel, but no luck. I still get a new sheet. However, the new sheet is just name "sheet6" or "sheet7" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Apps documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit), Form submit object function `.namedValues()` returns objects, you need to pass variables or objects with string datatype to the method `.insertSheet(sheetname)`

Implement this instead.

```
var destSheet = getSheet(ss, e.namedValues['Select The Worker:'][0]);
```

You will just need to specify the index of the array inside the object.

Comment: I am still have not been about to figure out how to specify the index of the array. Can you please give me an example. I updated the script and it is working, just without moving the reader row.